# How to make $filter available in all the controller function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. I'm currently injecting `$filter` to each of my controller function. I want to access the `$filter` function in all of my controller. Is it possible?

Comment: can you please post your code. How you injecting the `$filer` into `controller`

Comment: what issue do you have in injecting the filter inside the controller

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is having a reference to the service in the $rootScope (this could be done in the run block) and the prototype chain would make $filter available in all controllers.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.run(function ($rootScope, $filter) {
  $rootScope.filter = $filter;
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.filtered = $scope.filter('uppercase')("foo");
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdcCM/2/)